# Rails AJAX Get Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm sorry this is a broad question. I need some guidance though.

I have this AJAX call:

```
        $('#testyo').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "../messages/drew",
                success:function(data){
                 alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

which calls this rails method

```
  def show
    username = params[:id]
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.config.account_sid, Rails.application.config.auth_token
    @account = @client.account 
    received_messages = @account.messages.list
  end
```

it takes the params "drew", just as a test, but I don't know how to pass data back to the ajax call. the alert(data) isnt showing anything. I'm I missing something somewhere?

Comment: use format.json. and return json of `@account.messages.list`

Comment: So just add this at the end of my show method in the rails controller? format.json { render json: @account.messages.list}

Comment: @user3591126 can you post your logs and what you see in browsers console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MIME Types**

As mentioned, you'll be best using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for this, however, let me explain the way in which Rails will pass your data back

When you pass a request to any web application, your server / framework will have to determine the [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of that request. Mime types basically determine the type of request, whether it be a pure HTML one, JS one, etc.

Sending an Ajax request is essentially the same as sending an "HTTP" request, except that the ajax variant will have a different mime type. This allows you to adapt the functionality of your app to suit this (specifically with [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)):

```
#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html, only: :show
   def show
      username = params[:id]
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.config.account_sid, Rails.application.config.auth_token
      @account = @client.account 
      respond_with @account.messages.list
   end
end
```

This will send the relevant data back to the mime type you initiate the request with. To do this, you have to ensure you're sending the request you want, allowing you to process the response as you need:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#testyo", function(){
     $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: "JSON",
           url: "../messages/drew",
           success:function(data){
             alert(data);
           }
     });
     return false;
});
```

---

**Ajax**

You have to remember how Ajax handles requests / returned data.

Its known as [Asynchronous Javascript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - meaning it's intended to be an asynchronous technology.

This means that if you send a request via Ajax, the *idea* is that you'll receive a "portion" / "snippet" of data, which you can then append to your page. Of course, this is dependent on your application's structure, but the bottom line is that if you want to receive data back from your app, you'll have to design the ajax call around the data you want returned

Answer (score 1):

try adding this in the end of your show.

```
def show
    username = params[:id]
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.config.account_sid, Rails.application.config.auth_token
    @account = @client.account 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb AND if and only if you also want view of show
      format.json { render :json => @account.messages.list }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @account.messages.list, :status => 200 }
end
```

in your ajax call

```
    $('#testyo').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "../messages/drew",
            dataType: 'json'
            success:function(data){
             alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I'm still not getting an alert though. Does that mean it wasnt successful?

Comment: the /drew is the :id that the show method takes in? Thats what I thought atleast